# Deploy Mediawiki to Azure: no SSL Connection

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-web-app-service, mediawiki

I'm trying to deploy mediawiki to Azure Web App.  I created the app using Linux and PHP 7.3.  I unpacked WikiMedia 1.35.1 into wwwroot and used the browser to run the installation

I want to use MySQL for Azure as the database.  So I enter the mysql.database.azure.com parameters and press install.

The error I get is

```
Cannot access the database: :real_connect(): (HY000/9002): SSL connection is required.
```

The docs say I need to set $wgDBssl to true in LocalSettings.php.

The problem is that LocalSettings.php does not exist yet.  How do I specify an SSL connection during installation?

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to figure out the same dilemma and hoping someone with more PHP knowledge can provide a better answer. As a work around, you can disable "Enforce SSL" on your MySQL database in Azure. Then you can run the setup, create the localSettings.php file. After which you can add the settings for $[wgDBssl](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDBssl) and re-enable enforce ssl setting.

To my knowledge, a connection to the database is being using the "/includes/installer/MysqlInstaller.php" when running the setup. In the "DatabaseMysqli.php" and "Database.php" of /includes/libs/rdbms/database/ directory these two files are used for connecting to the database when running any query.

I am trying to see if there is a way to set the SSL setting in these 3 files first then run the setup and application. Apologies that I've entered this as an answer also. I am new to StackOverflow and cannot create comments yet.

Comment: Ok...I gave you an upvote...that should help out.  Yes your approach will work.  However I am loathe to disable this SSL setting.  My workaround is slightly different.  I connect to a local MySQL database on my machine and then upload the settings file to Web App.  But like you I am still looking for a clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this issue by forcing the following clause in `/includes/libs/rdbms/database/DatabaseMysqli.php` to always be true by adding `|| true` at the right place between the two closing parentheses:

```
if ( $this->getFlag( self::DBO_SSL ) || true ) {
    $flags |= MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL;
    $mysqli->ssl_set(
        $this->sslKeyPath,
        $this->sslCertPath,
        $this->sslCAFile,
        $this->sslCAPath,
        $this->sslCiphers
    );
}
```

Maybe there's a more elegant way to make the original condition `$this->getFlag( self::DBO_SSL )` to evaluate as true naturally?

Comment: Ugh.  This is even less clean then @Xeno's answer.  But I gave you an upvote anyway to get you going.

Comment: I prefer not disabling SSL temporarily, even if it's not elegant. I posted it mostly to pinpoint the clause where the failure occurs. As there's virtually no reason NOT to use SSL, i don't feel too bad about doing this to prevent plaintext credential transmission during setup. Thx for the upvote, i created the account specifically to share this ;)